# Writing to Kinesis Firehose with Kinesis Agent from custom logs gathered in single line

Tags: regex, logging, amazon-kinesis, agent

So I have logs being generated all together in single line.

I would like to use Kinesis Agent on my EC2 instance to write these data to Kinesis Firehose.

I already use custom matchPattern with custom fieldNames but it seems that agent can't take more than one record from single line.

I test this on dummy data generated by python script. Samples here:

```
77.253.46.255 - - [03/Sep/2020:09:46:12 +0000] "PUT /explore HTTP/1.0" 200 4957 "http://www.moore.biz/post.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Android 2.3.5; Mobile; rv:48.0) Gecko/48.0 Firefox/48.0"  128.206.196.208 - - [03/Sep/2020:09:49:14 +0000] "DELETE /search/tag/list HTTP/1.0" 200 4998 "http://hernandez.com/explore/faq.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows CE) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.806.0 Safari/533.1" 75.217.144.114 - - [03/Sep/2020:09:51:04 +0000] "GET /wp-content HTTP/1.0" 200 5047 "http://www.mason.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_8) AppleWebKit/536.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.891.0 Safari/536.2"  17.39.118.208 - - [03/Sep/2020:09:52:27 +0000] "PUT /explore HTTP/1.0" 404 5094 "https://ellison-saunders.com/faq/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.4.2; Mobile; rv:42.0) Gecko/42.0 Firefox/42.0"  9.101.23.95 - - [03/Sep/2020:09:57:04 +0000] "PUT /wp-admin HTTP/1.0" 200 5034 "http://mcmahon-cooper.com/app/main/posts/login.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X 10_6_9 rv:3.0; af-ZA) AppleWebKit/535.43.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Safari/535.43.1"    43.182.24.1 - - [03/Sep/2020:10:01:55 +0000] "GET /posts/posts/explore HTTP/1.0" 200 4981 "https://pacheco.com/home.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) FxiOS/12.5b2439.0 Mobile/84P693 Safari/534.2"
```

I tried some diffrent agent configs. Here is one example:

```
{
  "cloudwatch.emiTMetrics": true,
  "kinesis.endpoint": "",
  "firehose.endpoint": "https://firehose.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
  
  "flows": [
    {
      "filePattern": "/tmp/access_log*",
      "deliveryStream": "web-log-ingestion-stream",
      "initialPosition": "START_OF_FILE",
      "dataProcessingOptions": [
        {
       "optionName": "LOGTOJSON",
       "logFormat": "COMMONAPACHELOG",
       "matchPattern": "([\\d.]+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] \"(.+?)\" (\\d{3})",
           "customFieldNames": ["host", "ident", "authuser", "datetime", "request", "response"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions how to resolve this problem?